# Export PBR material for the web

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, blend4web, gltf, webgl

How do I export PBR materials from blender to files formats for web frameworks?

Are there any easy to implement solutions like Verge 3d (I am aware verge 3d exists for Blender), where the node setup created in blender is easily translated. Basically is there a fork of Blender I can run on a browser, like Blender Lite possibly, which can translate basic material setups directly?

Currently, I have to bake all the textures in order to translate them.

Comment: I have not heard about any similar solutions... still what's the problem to just use Verge?

Comment: Baking complex nodes into a flat texture helps lower-end devices on the web render your content more easily.  Not all battery-powered mobile GPUs are capable of handling complex Blender node setups, but they can easily do texture lookups.  This is why [glTF uses textures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html), not nodes, for example.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541

Comment: @Alexander verge as far as I know is not open source like blender, which means I can't edit the end output to my liking although verge is quit a blessing for 3d designers trying to move to the web.

Comment: @emackey I agree with you but the workflow still feels like a lot of trial and error to get all the bakes right, however if we had some sort of exporter we might be able to preview things on the web quicker without spending hours getting a good bake. things like noise maps or mixing materials with multiple textures which can be edited on the fly and programmed to change on command.